# Using \colon or : in formulas?

Tags: math-mode

I noticed that in many documents you encounter `$f: X \to Y$` instead of `$f \colon X \to Y$`. Another example are quantified expressions: `$\forall x: P (x)$` versus `$\forall x \colon P(x)$`. I find the `\colon` visually more pleasing, however I sometimes think I seem to be the only one, given the overwhelming amount of documents that seem to use `:`. Is there a rule of thumb to decide where you should use either `\colon` or `:`?

Comment: In the AMS (American Mathematical Society) [Short Math Guide for LaTeX](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) you'll find both a recommendation (page 8) to use `f\colon a \to b` (rather than `f : a \to b`) and a general discussion of relation symbols.

Comment: Link for @LeonMeier’s comment: here’s [Getting up and running with AMS-LaTeX](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/amshelp/2.3/amshelp.pdf) (v2.3, dated 2013, appears to be the most recent version), from [Phil Hirschhorn’s webpage](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/#amshelp).

Comment: [Up-to-date (public) link to the AMS Short Math Guide for LaTeX](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Both `:` and `\colon` typeset a colon, but `\colon` is a punctuation symbol, while `:` is considered as a relation symbol as regards to spacing.

The main use of `:` is in set descriptions

```
\{\, x : x \notin x \,\}
```

(somebody uses `\mid` for this, where a simple `|` would be wrong; thin spaces after `\{` and before `\}` are recommended by Knuth, be consistent in using them or not).

Conversely, `\colon` *should* be used for mappings

```
f\colon A \to B
```

but unfortunately many writers don't make this distinction and use `:`, getting a wrong spacing.

The rule to follow is just the same: use `\colon` when it's a "punctuation colon", use `:` when it represents a relation between what's at its left and at its right. In something like "for all x:" I would consider the colon as punctuation, so `\forall x\colon`

Note that the `amsmath` package changes the definition of `\colon` so that it's not exactly the same as a punctuation symbol:

```
\renewcommand{\colon}{\nobreak\mskip2mu\mathpunct{}\nonscript
  \mkern-\thinmuskip{:}\mskip6muplus1mu\relax}
```

This adds a bit of space before the colon, which seems more right than with a simple `\mathpunct`.

Comment: And use `:` for ratios. e.g. `$x:y:z = 3:4:5$`.

Comment: @LeoLiu Alternatively, `\mathbin{:}` could be used. Which one is a matter of personal taste. Most important is consistency across the document.

Comment: How does one distinguish between "punctuation" and "relation"?  The notation `f\colon A\to B` *does* denote a relation between `f` and `A\to B`, namely the relation "has type".  And I don't see in what sense the colon in `\{\, x : x\notin x \,\}` denotes a "relation" between `x` and `x\notin x`.

Comment: @MikeShulman It's a matter of conventions; usually the colon for maps is considered as punctuation, the one in set descriptions as a relation symbol. Be coherent in your document.

Comment: There's also a colon product, isn't there? I'd start typing the equation [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ColonProduct.html) as `$\mathbf{AB}\mathbin{:}\mathbf{CD}...`, since the colon appears to be a binary operator.

Comment: Just for clarity, the usual recommendation to use `\,` after `\{` and before the matching `\}` is _only_ in case the set involves a set descriptor (with the colon). By contrast, use `\{a, b, c\}` _without_ the thin spaces in case of an explicit enumeration of elements.

Comment: @egreg (or anybody else): Would it also be correct to use `:` when we typeset sets of the form `\{\, x\in\mathbb{R} : x\notin x \,\}` ? The difference is now the introduction of `\in\mathbb{R}`, which might obscure the objects that we want to relate to one-another (and rewriting the set as `\{\, \mathbb{R}\ni x : x\notin x \,\}` is not an option).

Comment: Can you clarify in your answer what objective criterion makes the spacing in `$f : A \to B` "wrong"? Or, if this is an opinion, however widely (?) held, can you make that explicit? Maybe many of the writers you refer to actively choose that option because it looks better (e.g. less cramped) to them.

Comment: @E.P. I follow the AMS in this (and Knuth).

Comment: @egreg Ah, I see. It would be good to state that explicitly. The left-of-colon spacing in `$f \colon A \to B$` changes quite dramatically depending on whether `amsmath` is called or not (as you explain). In any case, that spacing is a subjective matter of taste, so claiming it is objectively wrong is not quite there.

Comment: And what if you use the colon as a division sign, like they do in some countries? Which one in that case?

Comment: @Andyc `\mathbin:`

Answer (score 17):

If you're trying to typeset a variable-has-type colon in type theory, you want `{:}` or `\mathord{:}` (they display the same).  For example, you'll get a nice looking STLC identity function with `$\lambda x {:} A . x$`.

See [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55512/how-to-change-default-for-spacing-around-binary-relations) for a more general discussion.

Answer (score 1):

OpTeX sets the `:` differently when its Unicode math is loaded. The reason is that MathClass-15.txt defines the `:` as punctuation mark. We left the plain TeX setting of `:` as relation and keep Unicode recommendation: `:` is `\mathpunct`.

Consequences: you can type `$f: A → B$` and the result is OK. Of course, there is slightly smaller spaces than LaTeX's `\colon` from `amsmath` does, but IMHO LaTeX defines `\colon` with bigger spaces than needed (because it is a bad compromise between Plain TeX default `:` as relation and desired punctuation). OpTeX is without compromises, the `:` is punctuation and you can type it naturally without any control sequences.

On the other hand, in cases like `$x \mathbin: y$` you need to use a TeX primitive control sequence `\mathbin` or `\mathrel` to get good spaces.

The reason of this decision is: the usage of `:` as `$f: A → B$` is much more common in math typesetting than usage of `:` in all other situations.