# How to change default for spacing around binary relations?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

In TeX and LaTeX, the math binary relations (like `=`, `\parallel`, `<`, `\le` ...) have a default (rubber-length) spacing to either side, which is too large for my liking. How can reduce it?

Comment: @Werner thanks for your answer! Now I know what to do (of course setting these skips to 0em is not what I want either).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This answer doesn't encourage modifying the spaces, since TeX does a great job already. It merely discusses the concepts of spacing around math elements.

Spacing around math operators are discussed in the [`mathmode` documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) (section **11 Space**, p 28). Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\func}{f(x) = x^2 + 3x_0 \cdot \sin x}% Function
\begin{document}
\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{array}{rl}
    \mbox{default} & \func \\
    \verb|\thinmuskip=0mu| & \setlength{\thinmuskip}{0mu} \func \\
    \verb|\medmuskip=0mu| & \setlength{\medmuskip}{0mu} \func \\
    \verb|\thickmuskip=0mu| & \setlength{\thickmuskip}{0mu} \func \\
    \mbox{all set to zero} & \setlength{\thinmuskip}{0mu}\setlength{\medmuskip}{0mu}
      \setlength{\thickmuskip}{0mu} \func
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

To manually adjust the amount of space around a symbol, you can change it to an ordinal symbol by wrapping it in braces - for example `{=}` - and then add the space your want around it: `\,{=}\,`. Here's another example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{rc}
      \mbox{default} & x = x \\
      \verb|\mathbin| & x \mathbin{=} x \\
      \verb|\mathrel| & x \mathrel{=} x \\
      \verb|\mathord| & x \mathord{=} x \\
      \verb|{ }| & x {=} x \\
      \verb|\,{ }\,| & x\,{=}\,x \\
      \verb|\;{ }\;| & x\;{=}\;x \\
      \verb|\:{ }\:| & x\:{=}\:x
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Negative spaces, although not shown is obtainable via `\!`. Of course, you can also use other spacing macros like `\hspace`.

Also see [What is the difference between `\mathbin` vs. `\mathrel`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38982/5764) for a discussion between the difference in spacing around binary and relational operators.

Answer (score 55):

Werner already explained that you have to change `\thickmuskip` if you want to change the default. However, I don't quite agree with Werner that TeX does a great job already; I also think that sometimes the spacing to either side is too large. The default `\thickmuskip` is

```
5mu plus 5mu
```

so it can stretch from `5mu` up to as much as `10mu`. (This stretching will only happen for inline math, not in displayed math.) While I like the `5mu`, I think the added stretch is too much, and I think *a little* shrink is OK, too. So my preamble usually contains

```
\thickmuskip=5mu plus 3mu minus 1mu
```

Thus, I don't change the "standard" `5mu`, but the space can only stretch to `8mu`, and I allow it to shrink to `4mu`. (If you wonder what a `mu` is: it's one 18th of an `em` from family 2, the symbols family.)

For comparison, the following picture shows in the first line how it looks with the defaults, and in the second line how it looks with my modifications

[image: maximum stretch and shrink]

It's not *much* of a difference, but I like the second line better. Note that the default `\medmuskip` (used around binary operations) is

```
4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
```

i.e., it can shrink to *zero*. Personally, I don't like that either, so I have

```
\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 3mu
```

in my preamble – see the difference in the picture, too!

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes! I wholeheartedly agree with you, good sir. It might be nice to add that `1 \fam2 em` is `18mu` (or maybe putting it the other way around)?

Comment: @morbusg: Is it OK like I did?

Comment: Yes, that's actually much nicer way to put it. `:-)`

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Very good disagreement!

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for the edit! (So, you still disagree? `:-)`)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: I think your modification of `\thickmuskip` is agreeable. Do I still disagree? I never have. +1!