# Change spacing around binary operators

Tags: spacing, math-operators, inline, displaystyle

I'd like to change spacing around binary operators and this issue is discussed there:
[How to change default for spacing around binary relations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55512/how-to-change-default-for-spacing-around-binary-relations)

Is there way how to change spacing in `math` and `displaymath` separately?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\everydisplay` can be used to make a different setting for displayed equations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\medmuskip=0mu %    
\everydisplay{\medmuskip=10mu\relax}

\begin{document}
  \centering
  $a+b=c+d$
  \[ a+b=c+d\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Best solutions are the simple ones. Thanks a LOT.