# different spacing aroung equal sign for display/text mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, pdftex

as I wanted to increase the space surrounding the = sign in my equations, I changed the thickmuskip length in the preamble

```
\setlength{\thickmuskip}{14mu}
```

It works fine, and I like the result in display-style equations. The problem is that it also affects equations written in text-style (ie those with $$) and there it does not look good. How can I get a different spacing around = in display and text mode?

Thanks

Comment: Does the answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123323/change-spacing-around-binary-operators work for you?  (I've assumed your qn is a duplicate and voted to close.)

Comment: Yes the question is the same. Sorry I looked for it but could not find it. Thanks

Comment: However adding `\everydisplay{\medmuskip=10mu\relax}` as suggested in the answer causes an error for me, in the amsmath package: `\begin{split} won't work here`. The document builds perfectly without the `\everydisplay`

Comment: Solved with `\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\thickmuskip=14mu\relax}`. See [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5148/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-in-math-equations) by Matthew Leingang