# squeezing the equation fonts

Tags: equations

I have a set of equations which are defined below

```
\begin{figure*}[h] \label{eq1}
\begin{alignat}{2}
   & E_{\mathrm{access}}    && = E_{\mathrm{read}} + E_{\mathrm{write}} 
                               = E_{\mathrm{R\_L1}} + E_{\mathrm{R\_lower}} + E_{\mathrm{W\_L1}} + E_{\mathrm{W\_lower}} \label{equation1} \\
   ....
\end{alignat}   
\end{figure*}
```

The output produced is logically correct. However, I want to use smaller fonts and reduce the distance between symbols. For example, the distance between T+D, N*E....

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Apart from using a different font size (say `\small`), see [How to change default for spacing around binary relations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55512/5764) (possible duplicate?) where you can set/adjust the lengths `\thickmuskip`, `\medmuskip` and/or `\thinmuskip`. Each affects different spaces around different components.

Comment: You may want to omit all `\times` instuctions: They take up a lot of space *and* they are redundant. Separately, are you using `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)` to create the large round parentheses? They look disproportionately large. Using `\bigl[` and `\bigr]` will take up less space.

Comment: two column figures can not be `h` (and you should never use `h` on its own anyway) so that should be `\begin{figure}` or `\begin{figure}[htp]` depending (examples should be a complete document)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.s However it seem that `\small` doesn't work in `alignt` environment.

Comment: @mahmood: Place `\small` outside the `alignat` environment but still in your `figure` float.