# How do I define \times as a math symbol

Tags: math-mode

I want to declare $5\times 5$, so that the spacing comes out right.

When I type $2 \times (8+8+1)$, the spacing next the `x` is always bigger than that next to the `+`.

In order to fix this I want to define `$\times$` as a binary operator, same as the `+`.

I try and do this, but that fails.

`\DeclareMathSymbol{\xx}{\mathbin}{AMSb}{\times}`

`$2\xx(8+8+1)$`

outputs

`2 −1,0,1,−1.3,1.3,−1,0,1 [7] ∗ 2(8 + 8 + 1)`.

Comment: Your claim “the spacing next the `x` is always bigger than that next to the `+`” is *not* true. Please try `$2 \times (8+8+1)$\par$2 + (8+8+1)$` and you will see that the spacing around `\times` is exactly the same as the `+`. I think you are “tricked” by the symbol itself. The `\times` *looks* smaller than the `+`, so you *feel* that there is more surrounding space.

Comment: @RuixiZhang Ah, I see. OK. You are right.

Comment: My problem was fixed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55512/how-to-change-default-for-spacing-around-binary-relations The problem is that `a x b` is very common in the text and Latex loves to stretch these occurrences to fix its spacing issues. By limiting its room for maneuver `a x b` does not always look so stretched out all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\times` symbol is slightly narrower than `+`, but (at least in Computer Modern) they have equal width bounding boxes.

Add to this that the shape of `\times` may make the space after it look a bit wider.

Anyway, `\times` *is* declared as a binary operation symbol.

A visual comparison may clear up things:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt} % hairline
\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule} % don't add space
\newcommand{\bplus}{\mathbin{\fbox{$\m@th+$}}}
\newcommand{\btimes}{\mathbin{\fbox{$\m@th\times$}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$2 \times (8+8+1)$

$2 + (8\times 8\times 1)$

$2 \btimes (8\bplus 8\bplus 1)$

$2 \bplus (8\btimes 8\btimes 1)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not on a computer, so I can't check, but... Why the `m@th`? Thanks!

Comment: @Rmano Avoids the possible setting of `\mathsurround`. It's usually set to zero, but it's good practice to add `\m@th` for greater safety.