# Prevent LaTeX from stretching math

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Is there any package or local environment that prevent LaTeX from stretching math?
I would basically like the result to be just as if every `$...$` was replaced by `${...}$`.

Comment: Hmmm... really? Can you show your use case?

Comment: I find spacing around binary operators too large, especially around ```\leq``` that I use a lot. The answer of Henri Menke made me found that I am not the only one, and a more reasonable answer than no stretching can be found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58487/205684

Comment: You could redefine `\(` and `\)`, but that won't save you any keystrokes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove stretch and shrink from all the muskips.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\hbox to 100pt{$a + b$}

\setlength{\thinmuskip}{1\thinmuskip}
\setlength{\medmuskip}{1\medmuskip}
\setlength{\thickmuskip}{1\thickmuskip}

\hbox to 100pt{$a + b$}

\end{document}
```

[image]