# How to typeset a math function from and to a domain

Tags: math-mode, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using \colon or : in formulas?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37789/using-colon-or-in-formulas)

Currently I use

```
f\colon A \to B
```

to define a function map.

I do not know whether this is better than

```
f:A \to B
```

What's the best way? Sometimes the spacing looks ugly.