# Equation alignment creating unwanted space

Tags: math-mode, align

I am defining some text in a `align`, but no matter how i place the `&` symbol to create the alignment i get a space between the first chars.

```
\begin{align*}
H_0:& \text{Something.}\\
H_1:& \text{Something.}\\
\end{align*}
```

Basically i dont want a space between `H_0`, but rather after the colon.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to get? Should it be a colon like in normal text? See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37789) for some discussion about colons in math-mode!

Comment: It looks like you are using equation alignment commands to align something that is not an equation. I suggest using a simple `tabular` and putting `$H_0$`, `$H_1$` inside it.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, very good point!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you are running in to is that the `:` is treated as a relational operator and thus with white space around it. The white space after a relational operator disappears if followed by the `&`-command of the `align` environment. You will see this problem a lot on this page when seeing equation which are aligned to the right of their `=`-sign. In order to protect the white space, you would have to type `H_0:{}&\text{}` or `H_0&:\text{}` here.

However, it seems as if you do not want to have a relational operator here. There are three possible ways: The relational operator `:`, the "maps to" symbol `\colon` or the 'normal' text colon `\text{:}`. The following shows the differences:

```
\begin{align*}
&H_0:x\\
&H_0\colon x\\
&H_0\text{: }x
\end{align*}
```

[image]

You can see the different spacings here. And you may have noticed that the text-colon needs to be followed by a white-space, as there is no space between normal symbols (not operators) in math-mode.

---

In the following, I will show an MWE with two possible solutions of your desired alignment. I will use the two cases I believe you would like to have.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    
\begin{align*}
    H_0\text{: } &\text{Something.}\\
    H_1\text{: } &\text{Something.}
\end{align*}
% or identically
%\begin{align*}
%   H_0&\text{: Something.}\\
%   H_1&\text{: Something.}
%\end{align*}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
    H_0\colon &\text{Something.}\\
    H_1\colon &\text{Something.}
\end{align*}
% or identically
%\begin{align*}
%    H_0&\colon \text{Something.}\\
%    H_1&\colon \text{Something.}
%\end{align*}
```

[image]