# Set notation: \colon vs :

Tags: typography

Does the definitive way to write the colon, when writing sets in the form `\{x\in A : P(x) \}` exist and if there is one, which is it?

(Two approaches exist. Either writing it as I just did (this is seemingly endorsed by the tex.SX community, as I have seen it being used multiple times in different questions) or writing it as  `\{x\in A \colon P(x) \}`. This is the way LaTeX-companion proceeds.)

Comment: This is either a duplicate of or heavily related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37789/

Comment: A more general input would be `\set{x \in A\given P(x)}`, which would let you decide afterwards the look you want. Not answering the question, but would definitely help in case you need to change the output at the end. If you don't like that whole input, just defining `\def\given{:}` would be enough `\{x\in A\given P(x)\}` and you can change the definition whenever you want `\def\given{\colon}`, or even `\def\given{\mid}`.

Comment: I'd prefer `:`, but others prefer `\colon`: just be consistent.

Comment: Thanks for all the info (@Manuel nice/elegant idea, thanks!). Weird how I missed the duplicate question, usually I try not to post question that already have an answer.