# Customising enumerate lists - Problem with adding colon

Tags: enumerate

I am trying to add a colon after item number in enumerated list but this produces an error.

Here is my normal MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\newenvironment{xenumerate}%
{\begin{enumerate}\renewcommand\labelenumi{§\theenumi}}%
{\end{enumerate}}%
\begin{document} 
\begin{xenumerate}
\item first
\item second
\end{xenumerate} 
\end{document}
```

Works like a charm. When I add colon after it it produces different errors:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\newenvironment{xenumerate}%
{\begin{enumerate}\renewcommand\labelenumi{§\theenumi\colon}}%
{\end{enumerate}}%
\begin{document} 
\begin{xenumerate}
\item first
\item second
\end{xenumerate} 
\end{document}
```

Anyone has an idea how I solve this but without using packages like `enumerate` and `enumitem` because they clash with some other things I have?

Comment: Why not use something like `\renewcommand\labelenumi{§\theenumi:}}`?

Comment: So simple! If you post this as answer I will accept it. I am also interested in why `\colon` is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following MWE should give you the desired result. You can sinply use `:` instead of `\colon` which is a  ['punctuation colon'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37791/134144) in math mode and therefor does not work in text mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\newenvironment{xenumerate}%
{\begin{enumerate}\renewcommand\labelenumi{§\theenumi:}}%
{\end{enumerate}}%
\begin{document} 
\begin{xenumerate}
\item first
\item second
\end{xenumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image]