# Customize counter using tcolorbox?

Tags: numbering, theorems, tcolorbox

By now I've spend a lot of hours to find a way to customize the "Counter" inside `tcolorbox` package. I wanted to put a definition in a `tcolorbox` as below. [image]

In order to get this formation for definition, I used the following command (see `\tcbset{...}`):

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage[round,sort,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{float,rotfloat} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % need for figures
\usepackage{verbatim}   % useful for program listings
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref,url}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\tcbset{
defnstyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape, fontupper=\slshape,
arc=0mm, colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black},
}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,crefname={definition}{definitions}]%
{defn}{Definition}{defnstyle}{defn}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Limits and Derivatives}

\section{First Section}

\begin{defn}{One}{one}
Eine Funktion $f:~I\to\mathbb{R}$ auf einem Intervall $I$ hei\ss{}t in
$x_0\in I$ differenzierbar oder linear approximierbar,
wenn der Grenzwert
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=
\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}
\end{equation*}
existiert.
\end{defn}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{defn}{Two}{Two}
Eine Funktion $f:~I\to\mathbb{R}$ auf einem Intervall $I$ hei\ss{}t in
$x_0\in I$ differenzierbar oder linear approximierbar,
wenn der Grenzwert
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=
\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}
\end{equation*}

\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

But instead of counting definitions in the above pattern, I would like to count just 1, 2, 3 in each section (still I am interested to use `tcolorbox`). No chapter and section indication is necessary (see below). So, I tried to adjust the `number within=section` command in order to get my desire need but I am not able to get it at all.

[image]

It would be great if anyone could answer this question.

I greatly appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Remove the option `number within=section` and add (as normal code later on, *not* as option) `\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{tcb@cnt@defn}{section}
\makeatother` or alternatively `\counterwithin*{tcb@cnt@defn}{section}` (if you are using a LaTeX version newer than 2018-04-01)  instead.

Comment: You may want to consider writing `$f \colon I\to\mathbb{R}$` instead of `$f:~I\to\mathbb{R}$`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37789/35864. Regardless of how you stand on the `:` vs `\colon` issue I feel that the space introduced by `~` is much too large in this case.

Comment: @moewe: Thank you very much! It worked like a miracle! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a new LaTeX kernel (2018-04-01 or newer) you can use `\counterwithin*{tcb@cnt@defn}{section}` and drop the option `number within=section`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\tcbset{
defnstyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape, fontupper=\slshape,
arc=0mm, colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black},
}
\newtcbtheorem[crefname={definition}{definitions}]%
{defn}{Definition}{defnstyle}{defn}

\counterwithin*{tcb@cnt@defn}{section}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Limits and Derivatives}

\section{First Section}

\begin{defn}{One}{one}
Eine Funktion $f \colon I\to\mathbb{R}$ auf einem Intervall $I$ hei\ss{}t in
$x_0\in I$ differenzierbar oder linear approximierbar,
wenn der Grenzwert
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=
\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}
\end{equation*}
existiert.
\end{defn}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{defn}{Two}{Two}
Eine Funktion $f \colon I\to\mathbb{R}$ auf einem Intervall $I$ hei\ss{}t in
$x_0\in I$ differenzierbar oder linear approximierbar,
wenn der Grenzwert
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=
\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}
\end{equation*}

\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two colorboxes with a definition. Both are numbered only as "1" in their respective section.]

If you are still using an older version of the kernel you'll want to try

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{tcb@cnt@defn}{section}
\makeatother
```

instead of

```
\counterwithin*{tcb@cnt@defn}{section}
```

---

You can of course also go the opposite way

```
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,crefname={definition}{definitions}]{defn}{Definition}{defnstyle}{defn}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thetcb@cnt@defn}{\arabic{\tcb@cnt@defn}}
\makeatother
```

---

Both of these methods have the disadvantage that they rely on the internal name of the `tcolorbox` counter name (`tcb@cnt@<counter>`). If you stick to `tcolorbox`-only commands, you can avoid this reliance on the internal name at the cost of a more complex definition with `number freestyle`

```
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,number freestyle=\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter},
  crefname={definition}{definitions}]{defn}{Definition}{defnstyle}{defn}
```

Comment: I work on Overleaf but is seems `\counterwithin*{tcb@cnt@defn}{section}` does not work. But the other option perfectly works. Thank you!

Comment: @CMP Yes, as I said, `\counterwithin*` needs a new LaTeX kernel. Overleaf run an outdated version of LaTeX, where you can load the `chngcntr` package to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

Use number freestyle to format the number. And don't use the ae package - this is obsolete since a long time.

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage[round,sort,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float,rotfloat}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % need for figures
\usepackage{verbatim}   % useful for program listings
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref,url}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\tcbset{
defnstyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape, fontupper=\slshape,
arc=0mm, colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black},
}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,crefname={definition}{definitions},
number freestyle=\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}]%
{defn}{Definition}{defnstyle}{defn}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Limits and Derivatives}

\section{First Section}

\begin{defn}{One}{one}
Eine Funktion $f:~I\to\mathbb{R}$ auf einem Intervall $I$ hei\ss{}t in
$x_0\in I$ differenzierbar oder linear approximierbar,
wenn der Grenzwert
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=
\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}
\end{equation*}
existiert.
\end{defn}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{defn}{Two}{Two}
Eine Funktion $f:~I\to\mathbb{R}$ auf einem Intervall $I$ hei\ss{}t in
$x_0\in I$ differenzierbar oder linear approximierbar,
wenn der Grenzwert
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=
\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}
\end{equation*}

\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

[image]